Does any country make it illegal to possess a Starlink mini?
Does any country make it illegal to possess a Starlink mini?

Franck, your question implies you are asking about a country that has a certification process for transmitting devices, but that might ban this particular device for some reason other than it just not having yet completed the application, testing, etc. and received approval. (in other words, fully capable of meeting certification standards, but banned based on functional purpose or intent...) Is this what you meant? That's how I interpreted it, but the answer below presumes it would have been illegal to use before certification which seems so obvious as to not be useful...

@MichaelHall thanks, I'm interested in any cases where possessing a Starlink mini is illegal (i.e., regardless of whether a country has a certification process)

Once a question has been answered, it's not nice to change it in a way that invalidates the answers.

@Barmar, I understand, but is it better to leave it unclear so a wrong answer can remain because of a misinterpretation?  If you can edit a question for clarity you can edit an answer.

At the very least they should tell the answerer that they've clarified the question so they can update the answer accordingly.

The existing answer is still useful: illegal to sell, import and use by default until they are authorized by regulatory agencies

Are you asking for laws specifically targeting it, or being made because of it? Or are you looking for a list of the usual suspects of dictatorships like "North Korea, Afghanistan..."?

@nvoigt looking for both

RF emitting devices are illegal to sell, import and use by default until they are authorized by regulatory agencies through a certification process (e.g. US FCC, Canadian ISED, EU Radio Equipment Directive) so it would be illegal to be a consumer with a Starlink terminal at some time in pretty much any country.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
